# disabling property of a textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

when i click on a text box or start typing in a text box, its showing the previously entered string below it, i want to disable this property of a text box, how can i do this?

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="textbox" id="myTextBox" autocomplete="off" />
```

For an asp textbox

```
<asp:TextBox AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" ID="myBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

See **[autocomplete attribute](http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete)**

> The autocomplete attribute applies to
>   the text, password, select, textarea,
>   date-related, time-related, numeric,
>   email, and uri controls. The attribute
>   takes two values, on and off. The
>   default, when the attribute is not
>   specified, is on.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting `autocomplete="off"` as an attribute on the `<input type="text">`. Note that this isn't a standard attribute though, and will break HTML validation.

Answer (score 1):

this is a browser-issue

In Firefox: Extra -> Options --> Privacy --> Remember search and formhistory
(or something like that, I have Firefox in Dutch)

For IE: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000604.htm

Answer (score 0):

Set the autocomplete attribute in the form element to "off". Said attribute is not standard, but should work on most browsers.
See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)